# Why is my gameloop slightly faster than 60 per second?

Tags: game-loop, timestep

Here is my gameloop (taken from http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/) which is *supposed* to limit the game (logic) updates to 60 per seconds and render as fast as the device allows:

```
long nextGameTick = System.currentTimeMillis();
int loops;
final int maxFrameskip =5;                              
final int ticksPerSecond = 60;
final int skipTicks = 1000 / ticksPerSecond;
float dt = 1f/ticksPerSecond;
int ticks;
long secondCount;

onDrawFrame{

    //This loop will limit the logic update to defined value and render flat out
    loops = 0;

    while( System.currentTimeMillis() > nextGameTick && loops < maxFrameskip){
        updateLogic();
        //Update nextGameTic by adding skipTicks value to it, ready for next comparison
        nextGameTick += skipTicks;
        //Update loops value ready for next comparison in while loop
        loops++;
        ticks++;
        }                   
        //Once thses conditions are no longer true, exit while loop and render
    render();

    if (System.currentTimeMillis()>secondCount+1000){
        Log.v("Blocks","Ticks this second:"+ticks);
        secondCount = 0;
        ticks=0;
        }
}
```

However, when I run this, I'm getting anywhere between 62 and 65 as you can see from my logcat output:

[image: Count tics Ticks this second:63]

So, the loop doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Comment: Add Log statements inside the while loop, and see what the values are doing. Also make sure you initialize all the variables to begin with. (nextGameTick, tics, secondCount uninitialized)

Comment: Should skipTicks be a float? Because it will be 16 or 17 depending on the language.

Comment: The problem is that your skipTicks is being truncated to the value of 16. If you multiply 16 by 63 you will see that it is 1008 (just over a second). If you want to fix this you can either round up to 17 which will give you about 58 or 59 fps or you can change skipTicks and nextTick to a number type that supports decimals (float). Personally I would recommend just rounding the skipTicks value up.

Comment: You have an inconsistency in you spelling of the word "ticks". Not really important, but it bothers me :)

Comment: Their logic looks a lot like what is explained here: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ so it might be worthwile to read as a constant frametime is very hard to get right.

Comment: Thanks @RoyT.  I've already read this article, it doesn't really shed any light on it :-(

Comment: @AidanMueller, Oops. yep I see what you mean - corrected! Cheers :-)

Comment: Though you probably want VSync instead of manually limiting the frame-rate.

Comment: Could you elabote @Mr.Beast?  Thanks

Comment: VSync is waiting with processing of the next frame until the last frame is send to the monitor. The GPU sends frames in a fixed interval (which is typically 60Hz, e.g. 60 times per second). So by activating VSync your frame rate will be limited to the refresh rate of the display. Without VSync some unfortunate frames might be rendered but never displayed. How you activate VSync differs from framework to framework.

Comment: About VSync, it is usually 60Hz, but 59 and 120Hz are also common so you cannot rely on VSync for fixed-time-step logic.

Comment: @congusbongus I appreciate the edit, however, my original title was more apt, this question relates *specifically* to the logic component of the game-loop, not the loop as a whole. (The loop renders as fast as a device can handle which is it's normal behavior). The new title doesn't really sum up the question correctly.

Comment: @user22241 feel free to roll back the bad changes; I was only doing it to remove the *logic* tag, see [meta](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/1914/26250)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your main problem is likely this:

```
final int skipTicks = 1000 / ticksPerSecond;
```

Dividing an int by an int returns an int (the value is rounded down if needed), so `skipTicks` evaluates to 16. 1000 / 16 is 62.5 so you get around this many ticks per second.

To solve this the easiest solution would be to use a `millisecondsPerTick` variable (what you are calling `skipTicks` now) instead of `ticksPerSecond` and `skipTicks`, which would be an int. If you still need to find your ticks per second it is `1000d / millisecondsPerTick`.

If you want to continue defining your tick length in ticks per second for whatever reason, you could try something like this:

```
double timeCorrection;

while( System.currentTimeMillis() > nextGameTick && loops < maxFrameskip){
    nextGameTick += skipTicks;
    timeCorrection += (1000d / ticksPerSecond) % 1;
    nextGameTick += timeCorrection;
    timeCorrection %= 1;
    //update tick...
}
```

Although this isn't guaranteed to result in 60 ticks per second it will be closer than what you currently have. If `updateLogic()` often takes longer than the length of a tick then you may get less than the amount of ticks you want per second. The precision of `System.currentTimeMillis()` also varies between machines and could affect your ticks per second, or the time between two ticks.

In either case I would change `skipTicks` to `millisecondsPerTick` because I think it better describes the variable.

Comment: Thanks @alex, I'm a little confused over: "To solve this the easiest solution would be to use a millisecondsPerTick variable (what you are calling skipTicks now) instead of ticksPerSecond and skipTicks, which would be an int." - I mean shouldn't milliSecondsPerTick be a double rather than an int? Could you explain this one is a little more detail please?  Thanks!

Comment: I mean instead of `final int skipTicks = 1000 / ticksPerSecond` use `final int skipTicks = 16` (or `millisecondsPerTick` instead of `skipTicks` if you want). This prevents rounding during the division. It needs to be an int so it can be added to `nextGameTick` without rounding as well. `ticksPerSecond`, if you still need it, should be a double in this case and set as stated above.

Comment: Hey @Alex, thanks I'm just not getting this, I understand what you're saying about skipTicks being a int, but if I change that to an double as well as my ticksPerSecond variable as you suggest, should it not restrict the ticks per second to my actual 'ticsPerSecond' amount exactly? Ideally, what I'm after is my game loop restricting it's tics per second exactly to the amount I declare in my ticksPerSecond variable.  Thanks again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you change `skipTicks` and `ticksPerSecond` to a double you will get the same ticks per second as in your original code because it is rounded down every time it is added to `nextGameTick`, instead of being rounded down during the division. Since you want to define your tick length in ticks per second you could try my second example which should result in a value fairly close to what you declare, although it may not because of reasons stated above. There is no way to guarantee that you will get exactly as many ticks as you want per second, because continued..

Comment: Your game tick might take longer than you want the length of one tick to be depending on the amount of work you do in it and the speed of the computer you run it on

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I did like you said and am indeed getting between 60 and 61 ticks per second now which is more like it, I really wish I could stop it going above 60 but I guess that isn't possible?  The game is running on Android devices and on a low-end device I'm easily getting 60 ticks, so I'm not worried about a tick taking longer than 16.66ms (at present it takes only a fraction of that!)  My mission is really to stop it going over the amount I declare, but this is pretty close, so cheers! The bounty is yours for a well explained answer complete with code example :-)

Answer (score 7):

Alex's answer seems sufficient, but you say you want more detail, so here goes.

First, why does the gameloop from http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ deliver its desired frame rate while your version doesn't?  Because their integer division works out exactly:

```
const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 25;
const int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
```

SKIP_TICKS is 40 (with no rounding).  With increments of 40 msec, you get exactly 25 intervals in 1 second.

Your

```
final int ticksPerSecond = 60;
final int skipTicks = 1000 / ticksPerSecond;
```

has 1000 / 60 = 16.66667 but is truncated to 16 in integer division.  So instead of 16.66667 msec increments you're getting 16.0 msec.  This is about a 4% error.  There are 62 full intervals of 16 msec in 1 second, plus a leftover 8 msec.  (62 * 16 = 992 msec)  So I would expect you'd get a mix of 62 fps or 63 fps, about 50% each.

But you're seeing higher tick counts, 63-64 (maybe up to 65 as your question states).  What's going on?  I suspect the problem is that you're using a low resolution system timer that is too close to the computer's own basic system timer.  They aren't accurate (or repeatable) when timing intervals are too near the basic system timer interval.  For a discussion see

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=1329.0

where the first sentence states "There are significant flaws in the millisecond timer that ships with the normal JDK."  That message also points to a high resolution timer article and library that provides accurate timer resloution down to fractional msec.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077327/core-java/my-kingdom-for-a-good-timer.html

Those links are old, and I don't know the state of Java timers today, but the approach remains the same.  If you want precise and repeatable msec-range timing, use a high resolution timer and, along the way, stop doing integer math where the rounding error is anywhere near 4%.